# Modifying Calendar Views

Tags: sharepoint-calendar

How do I modify the calendar view to only show certain fields.
I have the "date" field selected as the time interval to show the date someone has picked, but above their name it has 12:00 am - 12:00 pm.

In my site column settings, I have that picked as Date Only, but it is still showing a time interval.

Please help!

Comment: Is it a calendar list, or a custom list with a calendar view? In the default calendar list, it shows the event title by default in the view, it doesn't show the date as the header

Comment: Which version of SharePoint?

Comment: @Flat Banana, I am using 2013.

Comment: @Mohamed Derhalli, It is a calendar list. I created a new content type using a item list instead of event, so that I could have more control over the fields.